# Check if product is in cart - Prestashop 1.7.4.2

Tags: php, if-statement, prestashop

I'm facing a problem with prestashop `1.7.4.2`.
I want to check if certain product ID is in cart before to allow customer proceeds checkout. If not, I want to display an alert.

In `1.6`, I could achieve this with :

```
{if !Context::getContext()->cart->containsProduct(784)}
message
{/if}
```

It doesn't work in `1.7.4.2`...

Any help will be greatly appreciated !
Thanks a lot & cheers !

Camille.

Comment: wow / it works..

Comment: I'm facing a (new) problem with prestashop 1.7.4.2. I want to check if certain product ID is in cart before to allow customer proceeds checkout. If not, I want to display an alert.
It works like this :
{if !Context::getContext()->cart->containsProduct(784)}
message
{/if}

+  I want to add a second if statement to check if there is a certain number of products in cart.

If there is less than xx products in cart AND/OR if cart containsProduct(784), I want to display message.

Any help will be greatly appreciated ! Thanks a lot & cheers !

Camille.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop all products in $cart var :

```
{assign var="inCart" value=false}
{assign var="idProduct" value=YOUR_PRODUCT_ID}
{foreach from=$cart.products item=product}
    {if $product.id_product == $idProduct}
        {assign var="inCart" value=true}
    {/if}
{/foreach}

{if $inCart == true}
    idProduct is cart !
{/if}
```

Comment: thanks  Vincent, it works, but as I said, I'm facing a (new) problem with prestashop 1.7.4.2. I want to check if certain product ID is in cart before to allow customer proceeds checkout. If not, I want to display an alert. It works like this : {if !Context::getContext()->cart->containsProduct(784)} message {/if} + I want to add a second if statement to check if there is a certain number of products in cart. If there is less than xx products in cart AND/OR if cart containsProduct(784), I want to display message. Any help will be greatly appreciated ! Thanks a lot & cheers ! Camille.

Comment: Do you know how can I do ?